# Rails: Search bar isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, activerecord, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to add a search bar for a database website I created, I found a tutorial and I "think" I did it correct.

When I do a search, such as "Judy Zhang", nothing shows up, even though it is in the database

my vendor.rb/concerns/models/app file

```
class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fotos      

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      Vendor.where('lower(contact_name) LIKE ?', "'%#{search.downcase}%'")
    else
      Vendor.all
    end
  end
end
```

I believe I didn't do the coding right. Very new to ruby on rails. What did I do wrong here?

code for index.html.erb/vendors/views/layouts/app

```
<body>
    <div class = "head">
        <h1>Vendors </h1>
       <div class = "image1" >
            <img src= "http://dx.deucex.com/i/logo.png" >
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <%= button_to "New Vendor", new_vendor_path, :method => "get" %>
            <%= button_to "Inventory", inventories_path, :method => "get" %>

            <%= form_tag vendors_path, :method => 'get' do %>
            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
            <% end %>

        </tr>
    </table>

<table>   
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact Name</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>

    <% for vendor in @vendors %>

    <tr>
        <td><%= vendor.company %></td>
        <td><%= vendor.contact_name %></td>
        <td><%= vendor.phone %></td>
        <td><%= vendor.email %></td>
        <body>
            <div class = "button1" >
                <td><%= button_to "Show", vendor_path(vendor), :method => "get" %></td>
            </div>
         </body>

        <td><%= button_to "Edit", edit_vendor_path(vendor), :method => "get" %></td>
            <div class = "button3">
                <td><%= button_to 'Delete', 
                                vendor_path(vendor),
                                method: :delete, 
                                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
            </div>

     </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

code for my VendorsController.rb/concerns/controller/app

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
     def index
        @vendors = Vendor.search(params[:search])
    end
    def show
         @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])
    end

     def new
        @vendor = Vendor.new
    end

    def create
        @vendor = Vendor.new(vendor_params)

        if @vendor.save
            redirect_to @vendor
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
       @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])
        if @vendor.update (vendor_params)
            redirect_to @vendor
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
   end

    def destroy
        @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])
        @vendor.destroy

        redirect_to vendors_path
    end
end

private
    def vendor_params
        params.require(:vendor).permit(:company, :contact_name, :phone, :email, :moq, :cost_per_item, :payment_method, :terms, :turnover, :returns, :notes)
    end
```

Comment: just edited my code where I currently have it as is

Comment: Only problem is when I do a search, nothing show up. Even if the search is in the database

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code in `Vendor` to

```
class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fotos      

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      Vendor.where('lower(name) LIKE ?', "'%#{search.downcase}%'")
    else
      Vendor.all
    end
  end
end
```

> My search bar isn't showing up

You should change the following

```
<% form_tag vendors_path, :method => 'get' do %>
```

to

```
<%= form_tag vendors_path, :method => 'get' do %>
# Notice that <%= %> evaluates and prints the output
```

Comment: Thanks! But somehow, my search bar isn't showing up

Comment: ok, just fixed that, but when I do a search, for example "zhang" which is in the database, nothing shows up

Comment: Try the updated answer we are now downcasing the user input as well as database value

Comment: I'm confused about that, what do you mean?

Comment: In case db value is `'Abc'` and user input is `'aBc'` we are downcasing both db value with `lower(name)` and user input with `search.downcase` so that they will match

Comment: So, I  assume I already down cased the input, how do I downcast the value?

Comment: `lower(name)` will downcase database value from `'Abc'` to `abc`

Comment: Oh ok! where do I put that?

Comment: check the method `self.search`

Comment: so it would be Vendor.where('lower(contact_name) LIKE ?', "'%#{search.downcase}%'") ?

Comment: I did that, but instead of name, I used contact_name, but I still don't see any results

Comment: Finally got it! Thanks so much!